# How to minify CSS and JS files using BundleConfig

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bundle, minify

I have been trying to bundle and minify my local CSS and JS files using ASP.NET MVC 4.6 Bundle Config.
I have tried the code below for CSS bundling:

```
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css/bundleStylesheets").Include(
                                                    "~/Content/css/custom-select.css",
                                                    "~/Content/css/main.css",
                                                    "~/Content/css/homepage.css",
                                                    "~/Content/css/asset-preview.css",
                                                    "~/Content/css/casestudy.css",
                                                    "~/Content/css/admin.css",
                                                    "~/Content/css/judgework.css",
                                                    "~/Content/css/submissions.css",
                                                    "~/Content/css/gallery.css"));

        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
    }
```

This creates a bundle CSS file. However, the bundle file is not minified. I was wondering if this is possible.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Run your application in release mode and check what happened.